# My application showing blank screen for 2 minutes after login for the first time

Tags: android

In my application for the first time when a user logged in, it is taking 2 min to show the home screen.in that time the screen showing as blank.and it is working fine with oreo version. and application is running fine on emulator also.but when i test with mobile it is showing blank. please help me to resolve it.

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    public static MyAppDataBase myAppDataBase;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    ImageView nav_header_profile;
    int job_rows_count, policy_row_count;
    ImageView img_view_gov_jobs, img_view_my_servant, img_view_gov_policies;
    TextView nav_hedaer_user_name, nav_header_mobile;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;
    DatabaseReference contactsRef;
    UserInfoTable infoTable;
    InternetConnection internetConnection;
    ContentObserver observer;
    String lastTimeStamp;
    String previous_timestamp;
    List<String> no_of_contacts;
    int contactscount;
    static UserDetailsAsycTask userDetailsAsycTask;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*getWindow().setEnterTransition(null);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(null);
        getWindow().setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false);
        getWindow().setAllowReturnTransitionOverlap(false);*/
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        PreferenceUtils.init(HomeActivity.this);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Bharat Next");
        floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        myAppDataBase = Room.databaseBuilder(HomeActivity.this, MyAppDataBase.class, "userdb")
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();

        internetConnection = new InternetConnection(HomeActivity.this);
        contactsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts");
        img_view_gov_jobs = findViewById(R.id.image_view_gov_jobs_for_you);
        img_view_my_servant = findViewById(R.id.image_view_my_servant);
        img_view_gov_policies = findViewById(R.id.image_view_gov_policies_for_you);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        nav_header_profile = header.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_profile);
        nav_hedaer_user_name = header.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_user_name);
        nav_header_mobile = header.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_mobile_num);
       // userDetailsAsycTask=new UserDetailsAsycTask(HomeActivity.this);

       // get();
       // infoTable=myAppDataBase.myDao().getUsers();
        infoTable=myAppDataBase.myDao().getUsers();
        String name = infoTable.getName();
        String mobile = infoTable.getMobile_num();
        nav_hedaer_user_name.setText(name);
        nav_header_mobile.setText(mobile);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //    initializeContactUpdatesReceiver();

       // getContactTimeStamp(HomeActivity.this);

        if (PreferenceUtils.GetLogin()) {
            InitializeSession();
        }

       /* mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);*/
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        // Set up the tabs for ViewPager

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(HomeActivity.this);


        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        img_view_gov_jobs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //govJobs();
                if (internetConnection.checkConnection()) {
                    govJobs();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        img_view_gov_policies.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (internetConnection.checkConnection()) {
                    govPolicies();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

        img_view_my_servant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, WorkForActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
               // Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        nav_header_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, UserProfile.class));
            }
        });

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        // DialogManager.showProgress(HomeActivity.this);
        /*contactsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(infoTable.getMobile_num())){
                   //  DialogManager.hideProgress();
                    contactsRef.child(infoTable.getMobile_num()).removeValue();
                   // DialogManager.hideProgress();
                    CheckContactsFragment();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("test","the error is "+databaseError);
            }
        });


*/


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogManager.showProgress(HomeActivity.this);
                // contactsRef.child(infoTable.getMobile_num()).removeValue();
                // CheckContactsFragment();
                contactsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(infoTable.getMobile_num())) {
                            DialogManager.hideProgress();
                            CheckContactsFragment();
                        } else if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(infoTable.getMobile_num())) {
                            contactsRef.child(infoTable.getMobile_num()).removeValue();
                            DialogManager.hideProgress();
                            CheckContactsFragment();
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.d("test", "the error is " + databaseError);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

                    floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }


            }
        });
    }

    private void CheckContactsFragment() {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        // based on the current position you can then cast the page to the correct Fragment class and call some method inside that fragment to reload the data:
        if (1 == mViewPager.getCurrentItem() && null != fragment) {
            ((ContactsFragment) fragment).getContactList(HomeActivity.this);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeSession() {
     //   DialogManager.showProgress(HomeActivity.this);
        ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
        Call<SessionResponse> call = apiService.checkToken("Bearer " + PreferenceUtils.GetToken());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SessionResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SessionResponse> call, Response<SessionResponse> response) {
             //   DialogManager.hideProgress();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body().getCode() == 201) {
                        ShowAlert(HomeActivity.this);
                    } else if (response.body().getCode() == 200) {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, response.body().getMesg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (response.body().getCode() == 205) {
                        ShowAlert(HomeActivity.this);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SessionResponse> call, Throwable t) {
              //  DialogManager.hideProgress();
                onError(t);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        // close drawer when item is tapped
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.nav_item_jobs:
                if (internetConnection.checkConnection()) {
                    govJobs();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.nav_item_policies:
                if (internetConnection.checkConnection()) {
                    govPolicies();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.nav_item_my_servant:
               // showAlertForm();
              //  Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, WorkForActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                break;

            case R.id.nav_item_about_us:
               // Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, AboutUs.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                break;
           /* case R.id.nav_item_my_logout:
                PreferenceUtils.SaveLogin(false);
                PreferenceUtils.saveUserId("");
                PreferenceUtils.savePassword("");
                DeletedData();
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
                break;*/
        }
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return true;
    }



    public void DeletedData() {
        PreferenceUtils.deleteData();
        myAppDataBase.myDao().deleteUsers();
        myAppDataBase.myDao().deleteUserJobDetails();
        myAppDataBase.myDao().deleteUserPolicyDetails();
    }

    private void govJobs() {
        job_rows_count = myAppDataBase.myDao().getNumberOfJobRows();
        if (job_rows_count >= 1) {
           // getWindow().setExitTransition(null);
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, JobsList.class);
           // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        } else {
           // startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, JobUserForm.class));
            Intent intent =new Intent(HomeActivity.this, JobUserForm.class);
          //  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        }
    }

    private void govPolicies() {

        policy_row_count = myAppDataBase.myDao().getNumberOfPolicyRows();

        if (policy_row_count >= 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, PoliciesGrid.class);
          //  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        } else {
            //startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, PolicyUserForm.class));
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, PolicyUserForm.class);
           // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

           /* case R.id.action_sign_out:
                PreferenceUtils.SaveLogin(false);
                DeletedData();
                PreferenceUtils.saveUserId("");
                PreferenceUtils.savePassword("");
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
                break;*/
            case R.id.action_contact_us:
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, AboutUs.class));
              /*  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              //  intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "bharatnext3444@gmail.com");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "bharatnext3444@gmail.com");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));*/
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

   /* @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted
                contactsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts").child(infoTable.getMobile_num());

                contactsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(!(dataSnapshot.exists()&&dataSnapshot.hasChildren())){
                            CheckContactsFragment();
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we cannot show contacts of your friends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }*/

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

   /* @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        getContactTimeStamp(HomeActivity.this);
        // put your code here...

    }*/
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code of your MainActivity so that we can help you.

Comment: yes..sure.. i added my code to the question.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and see ButterKnife...

Comment: Its quite obvious. You are doing all your work and calculation on main thread. That's why the blank screen. Try to do heavy calculation using `AsncTask` or `Loaders`. But if you are using  `Android Architecture Components`, then i would strongly recommend using **`WorkManager`** to move all your database queries on seperate thread.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

Comment: you likely want to profile your apps to see which code is taking so much time

Comment: the reason is to show chat and contacts i am reading contacts without using any service..reading contacts is running on main thread...that is why my app is getting crashed...anyway thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

You tried with other real devices? It's same issue?
This type of error happen when VM heap is Low and in that secession you should increase your ADB emulator Heap to the minimum required.

Into your AVD Manager :

- Click Edit on your Emulator
- "Show Advanced Settings" at the bottom
- Go to: "Memory and Storage"
- Edit the VM heap value to 512 MB
- Finished

[image]

Comment: it is working fine in emulator.but when i install application to my phone..it is showing the blank screen

Comment: I can see you are collecting data in the main thread.If the data volume is large it may cause the delaying. You can try to collect data async way so that data collection job will do in background process . Let me know its works